# how to get value from array with 2 keys

Tags: php, arrays

i have array like

```
Array
 (
[1] => Array
    (
        [user_info] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Josh
                [email] => u0001@josh.com
                [watched_auctions] => 150022 150031
            )

        [auctions] => Array
            (
                [150022] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 150022
                        [title] => Title of auction
                        [end_date] => 2013-08-28 17:50:00
                        [price] => 10
                    )

                [150031] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 150031
                        [title] => Title of auction №
                        [end_date] => 2013-08-28 16:08:03
                        [price] => 10
                    )

            )

    )
```

so i need put in `<td>` info from `[auctions] => Array`  where is id,title,end_date  but when i do like $Info['id'] going and put `id` from [user_info] when i try $Info[auctions]['id'] there is return null how to go and get [auctions] info ?

Comment: Did you mean `$Info['auctions']['id']` instead of `$Info[auctions]['id']` (missing quotes around the word auctions) or is that your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach( $info['auctions'] as  $key=>$each ){
    echo ( $each['id'] );
}
```

Or,

```
foreach( $info as $key=>$each ){
    foreach( $each['auctions'] as  $subKey=>$subEach ){
        echo ( $subEach['id'] );
    }    
}
```

Comment: thank you how im stupid , hehe i try foreach( $info as  $key=>$each ) first and i forget to add ['auctions'] into it , thank you for answer

Comment: You have error in your `html structure`. Keep the `table opening and closing` tags outside the loop. Only loop the `tr` inside the `second foreach`

Comment: yep i notice this today hehe

Answer (score 1):

Given the data structure from your question, the correct way would be for example:

```
$Info[1]['auctions'][150031]['id']
```

Comment: 1 is userID and 150031 is item where he have in a watched list so they cant be always same and they always change

Comment: This was just an example. Use variables for dynamic access.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array =array();
foreach($mainArray as $innerArray){

$array[] = $innerArray['auctions'];
}

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
foreach($val as $k=>$dataVal){
    # Here you will get Value of particular key
    echo $dataVal[$k]['id'];

}
}
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit malformed. I don't know if this is due to a lacking understanding of the array structure or just that you had a hard time to explain. But basically an array in PHP never has *two keys*. I will try to shed some more light on the topic on a basic level and hope it helps you.

Anyway, what you have is an array of arrays. And there is no difference in how you access the contents of you array containing the arrays than accessing values in an array containing integers. The only difference is that what you get if you retrieve a value from your array, is another array. That array can you then in turn access values from just like a normal array to.

You can do all of this in "one" line if you'd like. For example

```
echo $array[1]["user_info"]["name"]
```

which would print *Josh*

But what actually happens is no magic.
You retrieve the element at index *1* from your array. This happens to be an array so you retrieve the element at index *user_info* from that. What you get back is also an array so you retrieve the element at index *name*.

So this is the same as doing

```
$arrayElement = $array[1];
$userInfo = $arrayElement["user_info"];
$name = $userInfo["name"];
```

Although this is "easier" to read and debug, the amount of code it produces sometimes makes people write the more compact version.

Since you get an array back you can also do things like iterating you array with a *foreach* loop and within that loop iterate each array you get from each index within the first array. This can be a quick way to iterate over multidimensional array and printing or doing some action on each element in the entire structure.

Comment: this is possible but when you have tons of arrays in 1 page and cant figure out a new array name its not helping

Comment: I was just explaining that what actually happens in both examples is more or less the same. Except that when you call it as a one liner you, of course, never create intermediate array and name those. Worth noting though is that large one liners accessing multidimensional arrays can be hard to debug ones an error arises since it might be hard to quickly see what in the array of arrays has a "wrong" value. A good IDE will help though.